# Can one use two Amazon accounts on one Kindle?

Tags: kindle, amazon, kindle-app, download

For historical reasons I happen to have two accounts on Amazon,
and I would prefer to keep both, as they are in different countries.

I have ebooks in both accounts. Can I access both accounts with the
same kindle or kindle app and download the books from both?

How can I do it?

Comment: You could try adding one of your accounts as a family member and sharing the books with that account. I don't know if this would work between Amazon accounts between countries, but please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question to an Amazon customer service. The answer I got was NO. I did recommended them to design a way to allow users to link their multiple accounts in whatever countries.

What I'm doing now is using an Android simulator on my desktop computer, where I can run a separate Kindle app and use a different Kindle account. The Android simulator I'm using is bluestack, and TBH it's not a bad experience.

But I'm still struggling to find a way doing so on my iPhone and iPad...  Hope someone else can update the answer.

Comment: Welcome to ebooks-SE. I know the Kindle app for android does work on an android simulator,
because I have that on my smartphone, which is a Linux phone.
But I do not like the Kindle app for android because it receives only
encrypted versions of ebooks, in a format that is understood only by
the android app, even when the book is not supposed to have DRM. It is
not the same format as the one used for Windows or Mac Kindle
apps. Hence I cannot manage privately my ebooks, and my kindle app
will know only one account.  I always feel that Amazon is doing its
best to give me a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

My answer shouldn't be treated as definitive, but I did google around a bit.

One youtuber claims that he can access books from two accounts by logging off the device with  his original account, logging on with  the second account, downloading the ebooks locally, logging off again and then relogging with the original account. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqSgRmTxwyM

Youtube commenters are skeptical -- and so am I.

You can try, but you might screw up one or both accounts in the process.

Amazon has a method to link ebooks within different accounts within a family -- but there are strict rules about eligibility, plus I highly doubt it would apply to accounts for amazons from different countries. https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201733400

In my opinion (I'm speculating here) one solution might  involve having two separate instances of an app running on a device -- one with each account. I don't think it's feasible though on either android or ios or native kindles.

Perhaps if you could find the unencrypted versions of the files you could transfer them to a second app capable of reading .mobi files. (I know you asked a question about that a little while ago).  Perhaps you can use an app like fbreader to  read unencrypted  .mobi files . https://fbreader.org/content/book-formats-supported-and-not-supported

It seems easier just to have two separate devices with different accounts registered on each one.

Here's a wild idea -- why not write the Amazon people and ask them if they might consider transferring ownership of the files from one account to the other  -- especially if you can demonstrate that you own both of them. I'm guessing that you aren't the ONLY Amazon.com customer  who has moved to a different country. After all, you clearly have bought the ebooks in question. (Don't keep your hopes up!

Comment: It's 2023, I just verified I can access e-contents purchased from 2 different amazon accounts, amazon.{co.jp, com}, on a single Chromebook where I log on separately with 2 different Google accounts, have `Kindle` app setup separately, with each amazon account.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for a solution, but I was in the same situation. I had an Amazon US account and an Amazon IN account. Both of these has a few eBooks. I installed the Kindle for Android app on my phone with one account. And then installed the Parallel Space app via the playstore  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl. Then selected the Kindle App to run another instance in the Parallel Space environment with the other account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We are not supposed to use comments for thanking, but since you are a new user, that is my way of saying welcome on SE. I guess, on my PC,  I could use a virtual machine ... but I am not sure about the ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon let me do this by setting up a “family”, but my other account is my business.

Comment: Welcome to ebooks-SE.  Thanks for this good suggestion, which actually was already made previously (by idiotprogrammer). However, it is unlikely to be accepted for 2 accounts in different countries. Duplicating an answer is no big issue for a new user, but some people react negatively when you duplicate answers ...  though in your case you add the fact that you did it successfully.

Comment: I saw his post, but it didn't touch on the business account aspect. I think that's why I'm allowed to have them linked, because that way it's not considered an arbitrary duplicate account.

Comment: Good remark. My comment was made because you are new here, and I wanted to warn you that some people are touchy on principle, and sometimes because they do not see the extra contribution. It occasionally helps to be specific about it in contrasting with previous answers. Another possibility is to simply ignore unwarranted negative comments and downvotes.  BTW, someone did downvote you without waiting for your explanation ... and he cannot undo it.

Answer (score 0):

My Kindle is associated with one Amazon account.
To get the books from another Amazon account in another country I download the books on my PC via the Kindle for PC application, using this other account.
I synchronize/ send these books to my Kindle via Calibre and connecting my Kindle via USB Cable. (see for example https://www.howtogeek.com/539829/how-to-transfer-any-ebook-to-kindle-using-calibre/)